# Copy decimal into byte array without allocations

Tags: c#

### The Dream

I'm looking for a way to copy a decimal value into a byte array buffer and then be able to read those bytes back into a decimal without any heap allocations. Ideally this wouldn't require an unsafe context.

### My Attempts

I've used makeshift unions in C# to do some crazy things before. It's a pretty cool way to just read memory any random way you want, but you've gotta be careful. You can get into corrupted states where a variable my explicitly be, for example `byte[]` but the value as viewed in the debugger is `int[]`. I didn't even know such a thing was possible!

NOTE: Marc makes a really important point in the comments below. You can't reliably convert numbers directly into bytes using an overlapping struct concept like this due to endianness. In this case you can safely use ints because the decimal type used 4 ints internally. Here's an [example] from protobuf-net's decimal serializer.

#### 1: struct union w/ decimal and byte[]

This first attempt tries to use the struct union concept w/ a `decimal` and `byte[]` field, both at the 0 offset, so they're taking up the exact same memory location. I could then write to one field and read from the other field.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
private readonly struct DecimalByteConverter
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public readonly decimal value;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public readonly byte[] bytes;

    public DecimalByteConverter(decimal value)
    {
        bytes = default;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

This doesn't even run w/out throwing -- type fails to load with the following:

```
System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'DecimalByteConverter' from assembly 'teloneum, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.
```

Apparently the CLR doesn't like them being overlapped -- but only because one is a value type and the other is a reference type.

#### 2: struct union w/ decimal and 16 bytes!

So I decided to remove the reference type! Now, the following *works*, or at least, it will work, but the ordering is all messed up. I can certainly can a big decimal number, run it through here, and then just make by field offsets such that it matches my test, but that just seems wrong -- plus, there's at least three zero bytes in every decimal I tried this for :) Maybe I just got lazy at the end... it is late after all.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
private readonly struct DecimalByteConverter
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public readonly decimal value;

    [FieldOffset( 0)] public readonly byte byte_1;
    [FieldOffset( 1)] public readonly byte byte_2;
    [FieldOffset( 2)] public readonly byte byte_3;
    [FieldOffset( 3)] public readonly byte byte_4;
    [FieldOffset( 4)] public readonly byte byte_5;
    [FieldOffset( 5)] public readonly byte byte_6;
    [FieldOffset( 6)] public readonly byte byte_7;
    [FieldOffset( 7)] public readonly byte byte_8;
    [FieldOffset( 8)] public readonly byte byte_9;
    [FieldOffset( 9)] public readonly byte byte_10;
    [FieldOffset(10)] public readonly byte byte_11;
    [FieldOffset(11)] public readonly byte byte_12;
    [FieldOffset(12)] public readonly byte byte_13;
    [FieldOffset(13)] public readonly byte byte_14;
    [FieldOffset(14)] public readonly byte byte_15;
    [FieldOffset(15)] public readonly byte byte_16;

    public DecimalByteConverter(decimal value)
    {
        byte_1  = default;
        byte_2  = default;
        byte_3  = default;
        byte_4  = default;
        byte_5  = default;
        byte_6  = default;
        byte_7  = default;
        byte_8  = default;
        byte_9  = default;
        byte_10 = default;
        byte_11 = default;
        byte_12 = default;
        byte_13 = default;
        byte_14 = default;
        byte_15 = default;
        byte_16 = default;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public DecimalByteConverter(int startIndex, byte[] buffer)
    {
        value = default;
        byte_1 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_2 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_3 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_4 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_5 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_6 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_7 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_8 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_9 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_10 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_11 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_12 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_13 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_14 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_15 = buffer[startIndex++];
        byte_16 = buffer[startIndex];
    }


    public static void Copy(decimal value, int startIndex, byte[] buffer)
    {
        var convert = new DecimalByteConverter(value);

        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_1;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_2;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_3;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_4;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_5;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_6;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_7;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_8;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_9;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_10;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_11;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_12;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_13;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_14;
        buffer[startIndex++] = convert.byte_15;
        buffer[startIndex]   = convert.byte_16;
    }

    public static decimal Read(int startIndex, byte[] buffer)
    {
        var convert = new DecimalByteConverter(startIndex, buffer);

        return convert.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The byte array for sure will need an allocation. You probably mean that the method should transfer the `decimal`s content to an externally provided buffer, or? Does [decimal.GetBits(Decimal, Span<Int32>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits) fit your needs?

Comment: Of course the buffer requires an allocation. I don't think this was ambiguous. Buffers are ALWAYS external to a method. I don't think this deserved a down vote. I'll prove a sample of what I'm looking for.
decimal.GetBits makes an allocation of int[4] -- so no, it clearly does not fit my needs.

-- why the down votes? I've added a sample method signature, so hopefully this removes the ambiguity.

Comment: @mhand: You referred to the `decimal.GetBits` method that returns an `int[]`, but Klaus *explicitly* referred to the overload accepting a `Span<int>` which *does* fit your needs (as shown in my answer). Please be careful before dismissing suggestions from those trying to help you.

Comment: I'd also strongly recommend following normal C# and .NET naming conventions even for throwaway sample code - all those unconventional underscores (and a type name starting with a lower case letter) can be really distracting.

Comment: "plus, there's at least three zero bytes in every decimal I tried this for" - that's not surprising. `decimal` only actually stores 102 bits of information - 96 bits of mantissa, 5 bits of exponent, and 1 bit of sign.

Comment: You might be interested in this article: [Fun with `__makeref`](http://benbowen.blog/post/fun_with_makeref/). Scroll to the section entitled "Use Case: Reinterpreting Variables."

Comment: Jon -- well then, I guess I'm the a-hole -- my apologies @Klaus. RE: conventions -- ohh the irony, I'm so anal about conventions/naming/consistency, but doing something as *dirty* as what I tried, I don't know, it somehow felt _right_ to make it hideous.

Comment: @JohnWu - awesome! I've _heard_ of these before but have never really read up/used them. Shame it can't handle reference types. and requires an unsafe context. It's _essentially_ doing the same thing I'm doing w/ my overlapping struct. Great read, thank you!

Comment: Side note: your existing 16-bytes approach is actually **actively dangerous** because of endianness. IMO you should use 4 overlapped `int` values here, *not* 16 `byte` values. The way the work will be quite different on other-endian CPUs. I linked an example of that 4-field usage in a comment on Jon's answer

Comment: @MarcGravell -- great point --  I overlooked that and left a note in the question that such a technique shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before .NET 5.0, this was awkward without some ugly hackery. From .NET 5.0, there are more methods accepting spans.

You can use the [`GetBits(decimal d, Span<int>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits?view=net-5.0#System_Decimal_GetBits_System_Decimal_System_Span_System_Int32__) method using a stack-allocated span, and then convert the four integers into the existing byte array however you want, e.g. with `BitConverter.TryWriteBytes`.

In the other direction, there's a `Decimal(ReadOnlySpan<int>)` constructor, so again you can stackalloc a `Span<int>`, use `BitConverter.ToInt32(ReadOnlySpan<byte>)` repeatedly to populate that span from the byte array, and pass it to the constructor.

As an aside, instead of accepting byte arrays and start indexes, you might want to embrace spans more widely through your code base.

Here's some sample code which does all of the above - it may well be possible to do it slightly more efficiently, but hopefully this gets the idea across, and this does avoid allocation:

```cs
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Copy(decimal value, int startIndex, byte[] buffer)
    {
        Span<int> int32s = stackalloc int[4];
        decimal.GetBits(value, int32s);

        var bufferSpan = buffer.AsSpan();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            // These slices are bigger than we need, but this is the simplest approach.
            var slice = bufferSpan.Slice(startIndex + i * 4);
            if (!BitConverter.TryWriteBytes(slice, int32s[i]))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Not enough space in span");
            }
        }
    }

    public static decimal Read(int startIndex, byte[] buffer)
    {
        Span<int> int32s = stackalloc int[4];
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> bufferSpan = buffer.AsSpan();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var slice = bufferSpan.Slice(startIndex + i * 4);
            int32s[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(slice);
        }
        return new decimal(int32s);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
        decimal original = 1234.567m;
        Copy(original, 0, bytes);
        decimal restored = Read(0, bytes);
        Console.WriteLine(restored);
    }
}
```

---

or the same thing using `MemoryMarshal`:

```cs
public static void Copy(decimal value, int startIndex, byte[] buffer)
    => decimal.GetBits(value, MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, int>(buffer.AsSpan(startIndex)));

public static decimal Read(int startIndex, byte[] buffer)
    => new decimal(MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, int>(buffer.AsSpan(startIndex)));
```

Comment: It should be noted that this works only on .NET 5.0

Comment: @KlausGütter I was just looking that up - looks like I can finally start the *long* process of retiring this hackola: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzKLM.png

Comment: For the OP's benefit: if you're not on .NET 5, here's the above hackery in all the dubious glory: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net.Core/Internal/PrimaryTypeProvider.Decimal.cs - see all the usages of `DecimalAccessor`

Comment: My main goal was removing heap alloc for GC reasons, this code is in a very heavy/low latency data feed. Now that there's options I'll have to bench.net each. Thanks for all the input!

Comment: Suggested improvement rather than the offset slice plus bitconverter: `MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, int>` (and `<int, byte>`) - more direct and allows a much simpler loop; caveat: any approach that uses the `byte` data directly (including the code shown in this answer, and via `MemoryMarshal.Cast`) may need to consider endianness

Comment: @MarcGravell: Could I suggest adding that as a different answer? It never hurts to have multiple options available. Or if it it's not terribly different, maybe you could edit it into this one as a partial alternative? It's more likely to be correct if you do that directly :)

Comment: edited in; also note: zero copy - everything happens direct to the underlying buffer

Answer (score 0):

In fact, consulting the MSDN example code, I found a simple way to do exactly this using this way:

```
        int[] data = decimal.GetBits(h);
        bool sign = (data[3] & 0x80000000) != 0;
        byte scale = (byte)(((data[3] >> 16) & 0x7F) + (byte)(!sign ? 0x20 : 0x00));
        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>() // For concatenation
        bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(data[0]));
        bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(data[1]));
        bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(data[2]));
        bytes.Add(scale);
        return bytes.ToArray();
```

And back:

```
        byte[] bytes = array.Take(13);
        byte scale = bytes[12];
        bool sign = true;
        if (scale >= 0x20)
        {
            sign = false;
            scale -= 0x20;
        }

        return new decimal(BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes,0), 
                           BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes,4), 
                           BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes,8), sign, scale);
```

I am using this code above to serialize/deserialize Decimals. Since MSDN documentation points that are bits that are unused in the last int (the first 16 ones and the last 3 ones, I convert the last int to an "signed scale" so I have less bytes to allocate. The original decimal size is 16-bytes long.